# Why will the RP-1 loading for SpaceX's Iridium-1 mission begin at T-00:70:00 as opposed to T-01:10:00?

Tags: spacex, launch-sequence

Why will the RP-1 loading for SpaceX's Iridium-1 mission begin at `T -00:70:00` - wouldn't it usually be written as `T -01:10:00`?

$\hspace{6cm}$[image: screen shot SpaceX's Iridium-1 press kit]

Screen shots (above and below) from: http://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/spacex_iridium1_press_kit.pdf

$\hspace{6cm}$[image: screen shot SpaceX's Iridium-1 press kit]

Comment: Maybe just a clerical error without any significance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody messed up.

It absolutely should be `-01:10:00`. My guess is that someone was counting backwards from `T = 0`, and didn't think long enough about what they were typing. Press kits are usually put together by PR or media relations people, who at SpaceX are probably on just as tight deadlines as the engineers. Mistakes will be made.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. Those darn humans!

Comment: @uhoh Those darn Vulcans, expecting everything to adhere to the rules of logic.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling... and [holding back our (future) development of warp drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Enterprise#General) for decades :) also discussed in [answers here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76018/51174).